# Slidingdrawer opens under VideoView

Tags: android, fragment, android-videoview, slidingdrawer

I'm using `Slidingdrawer` and fragments in it. One of my fragments has a `VideoView` which streams online videos and it takes about 1/2 of my layout. The problem is, whenever I click on the `slidingdrawer` it comes out behind my `VideoView`. and it just happens in this fragment and just under the `VideoView`. I just wonder how can I fix it ?

Also I tried to pause my video when I click on the slider but it still works with the same issue.

Comment: please paste some layout code here

Comment: did u get any solution ?

Comment: @r4jiv007 yes, I just create a Button on the VideoPlayer, and made it's backgroundColor = #ff000000 to be invisible, and it solved the problem , it was weird but I guess it was Android's bug that when a videoPlayer loads as a layer it comes to the above layer on some Android phones

Comment: yeah i agree with that !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's weird but I solved it by adding a `Button` on the `VideoPlayer` in the xml file, with `background="#ff000000"` to be invisible.